# How did Flamingo get the Mera Mera no mi?

Tags: one-piece

The only place we've seen them together is during the war. Long before Ace died, Flamingo disapeared (after talking to Moria).

So, how did he get the Mera Mera no mi? Is it a real one or just an artificial one made with Smile?

Comment: First: they didn't have to be together for him to get the fruit. Second: Doflamingo left *after* Ace died.

Comment: As we know devil fruits respawn to the nearest fruit, Doffy might have known this and brought the exact same fruit with him to Marineford, just in case Ace might die. He's smart like that to fully prepare himself in every situation.

Comment: It is also possible that with his extensive social power, he was able to gain hold of possession of the fruit from the Marines. Considering the fact that the Marines want to stop pirates, it would make sense that they would already be prepared to receive the fruit of any fruit holders that die on the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now we don't know how he got hold of the mera mera no me. (My guess is that we'll never really know.)

But it's definitely the real deal. Artificial fruits are zoan types and the mera mera no mi is logia.

Answer (score 2):

Doflamingo was there for the death of Ace, as were all the warlords. The situation with Moria happened afterwards.

From what we've seen with Smiley and the axolotl fruit, it seems that when a Devil Fruit eater dies, it takes over another fruit, somewhere in the world, and with Smiley that fruit happened to be very nearby. So it is possible that Doflamingo had an apple in his pocket which became the Mera Mera no Mi after Ace's death.

But there are many possibilities, the current owner of the Mera Mera is Sabo, which he gained possession of by defeating Diamanté and the others. He was definitely nowhere near Ace, it is also easily possible that Doflamingo did the same as Sabo did and just took it from whomever found it.